# Are questions based on fiction allowed?

Tags: discussion

Let's say there is a movie in which a meteorological even is depicted.

Would it be on topic to ask "is this a realistic representation? under which conditions?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that is on topic as an appropriate way to gain knowledge about earth sciences. Similarly, earth-building questions designed to understand realistic earth systems are on topic but circumventing reality is not.

Comment: Thank you. going to ask in a few moments.

Answer (score 0):

It feels to me like asking if it's realistic would be on topic, but asking about the mechanics of some fictional meteorological event would not be.

More verbosely, if they're asking about whether a fictional depiction of earth science stuff follows the models we have for how these things work in real life, that's actually a question about how things work in real life.  They've seen the movie, they understand what was shown in the movie, they just want to know if the world is really like that.

But if they're asking about the ramifications of some fictional earth science mechanic that they know doesn't actually exist in the real world, that's a question for one of the various fiction SEs, not here.

Comment: Just to note, I'm positing this answer as much to find out if this is really the way things work here as I am suggesting that it is my understanding of how things work here.